# Why customizing HttpMessageConverter in Spring MVC? Why we need to customize it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring. I didn't understand why we need to customize HttpMessageConverter of Jackson in Spring.

Comment: So what was missing from my answer? Just curious so I can complete it.

Comment: I can't flag two tick at the same time, although your answer is in very detail but i need a concept, which i get by read  that article.

Comment: Well that's not how it works here. But whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply said, for flexibility you can use default configuration or write your own to which fits your needs to automatically marshall/unmarshall Java Entities to and from XML or JSON. You could try to reads this for basics: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest